# Python Script Calling Make and Other Utilities

Tags: python, linux, scripting, makefile

I have a python script that invokes the following command:

```
# make
```

After make, it also invokes three other programs.  Is there a standard way of telling whether the make command was successful or not? Right now, if make is successful or unsuccessful, the program still continues to run.  I want to raise an error that the make was not possible.

Can anyone give me direction with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of the [`poll()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) and [`wait()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait) methods is the return code of the process. Check to see if it's non-zero.

Comment: Is poll() and wait() build into python or make?

Comment: `poll` and `wait` are methods understood by `subprocess.Popen` objects. Click the links in Ignacio's answer for more.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Didn't even realize it was a link!

Answer (score 0):

Look at the exit code of make. If you are using the python module `commands`, then you can get the status code easily. 0 means success, non-zero means some problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
if os.system("make"):
    print "True"
else:
    print "False"
```

Comment: Sorry. I don't think this works.  I just tested it out with calling a dummy program that never exists and it never goes to the false statement

Comment: This script will print True if make returned any errors, and false if it exited cleanly.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`subprocess.check_call()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call). That way you don't have to check the return code yourself - an Exception will be thrown if the return code was non-zero.